# Split large RTF file into multiple files

Tags: vba, split, ms-word, rtf

Please help :

I have large **RTF** file with about 400 pages. I want to split the RTF file into multiple files based on number of lines.

For example:

> I want to split every 15 lines into a new rtf file. Is this possible?
>
> I have managed to split the doc based on a new page but I need to split it based on number of lines. The macro I used to split the file based on new page is:

```
Sub BreakOnPage()
  ' Used to set criteria for moving through the document by page.
Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowsePage

For i = 1 To ActiveDocument.BuiltInDocumentProperties("Number of Pages")
  
  'Select and copy the text to the clipboard.
  ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\page").Range.Copy

  ' Open new document to paste the content of the clipboard into.
  Documents.Add
  Selection.Paste
' Removes the break that is copied at the end of the page, if any.
  Selection.TypeBackspace
  ChangeFileOpenDirectory "C:\"
  DocNum = DocNum + 1
  ActiveDocument.SaveAs FileName:="test_" & DocNum & ".doc"
  ActiveDocument.Close

  ' Move the selection to the next page in the document.
  Application.Browser.Next
Next i
ActiveDocument.Close savechanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
End Sub
```

Comment: so this is in word-vba? Can you please clarify what you expect the solution to be (though im not familar too much with word-vba, so can think you want macro or some vba code snippit, unsure)

Comment: @DanielBrose : Thanks for your concern. Yes this is word-VBA. Actually I am an iOS developer. I need to display one RTF file per page on a uipageviewController. So I need to split the large RTF file into multiple files that can be easily displayed on the UIPAGEVIEWCONTROLLER.  I am thinking to use a Macro or script to aplit this RTF file.

I have managed to split RTF on the basis of new page but I need to split it according to the number of lines that can be displayed on my UIPAGEVIEWCONTROLLER.

Answer (score 0):

though I am not into iOS programming, maybe this vba code might help you:

```
Sub SplitDoc()

   SplitAfterLines 15 

End Sub


Private Sub SplitAfterLines(xLines As Integer)

   Dim docCounter As Integer
   Dim docPath As String
   Dim lineMove As Long

   docPath = ActiveDocument.Path
   docCounter = 1

   Selection.HomeKey wdStory

   Do
       lineMove = Selection.MoveDown(wdLine, xLines, wdExtend)
       If lineMove < xLines Then
          ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 docPath & "\Split_" & docCounter & ".doc"
          Exit Do
       End If

       Selection.Cut
       Application.Documents.Add
       Selection.Paste
       ActiveDocument.SaveAs2 docPath & "\Split_" & docCounter & ".doc"
       ActiveDocument.Close
       docCounter = docCounter + 1
   Loop

   ActiveDocument.Close

End Sub
```

Though I am sure there is a cleaner way to do it, i hope this will help you go into the direction you want...

Comment: Thanks for your valuable time but I have managed it in ios itself.